# Change colour of specific characters in string in C

Tags: c, string, colors, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

Say I have some ASCII art in string presented as a variable as follows:

```
    char LOGO[3][40] = {
    "   /$$    /$$                       ",
    "  | $$   |__/                       ",
    " /$$$$$$  /$$/$$$$$$$ /$$   /$$     ",
```

I want to specifically show the `$` with a green colour within the terminal. The classic way of doing so is using ANSI escape codes between an instance/s of `$`.
Unfortunately, this is not viable since I have much more than three lines of this string, and it would be exhausting to do so manually.

Is there a much more viable way of changing the colour of specific characters within a string?

TIA

Comment: I suggest you do a search for an ASCII art editor, create whatever it is you want to display, then copy-paste the result into your source code.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Any editor in particular that you recommend?

Comment: Sorry, I'm now blind. And it's been years even before that that I did anything with ASCII art, not since using BBSes in the early 90s.

Comment: In 2022 you probably could use some GUI toolkit like [GTK](https://gtk.org/); notice that some terminal (or terminal emulators) might not support colors. You could also add web interaction to your program with libraries like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/). And some users are color-blind... or are running your program thru `ssh`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it is not my intention to create a GUI, the end product is a mini UNIX shell

Comment: Then study (for inspiration) the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or of [zsh](https://zsh.org/). Both are open source and implementing the features you want and both are coded in C. See also [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to produce green characters on the terminal, you do not need to change the definition of the logo, just test the characters and output the escape sequences as required:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char const LOGO[3][40] = {
    "   /$$    /$$                       ",
    "  | $$   |__/                       ",
    " /$$$$$$  /$$/$$$$$$$ /$$   /$$     ",
};

int main() {
    int green = 0;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < sizeof(LOGO) / sizeof(LOGO[0]); row++) {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < sizeof(LOGO[0]) / sizeof(LOGO[0][0]); col++) {
            char c = LOGO[row][col];
            if (c == '$') {
                if (!green) {
                    green = 1;
                    printf("\033[32m");
                }
            } else {
                if (green) {
                    green = 0;
                    printf("\033[0m");
                }
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
        if (green) {
            green = 0;
            printf("\033[0m");
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that solution with macros available, but an unefficient solution with an extra function is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ORIG_CHAR   "$"    
#define GREEN_CHAR   "\033[32m$\033[0m"     

#define NEW_STRING(n) str_replace( n, ORIG_CHAR, GREEN_CHAR)
      
char LOGO[3][40] = {
"   /$$    /$$                       ",
"  | $$   |__/                       ",
" /$$$$$$  /$$/$$$$$$$ /$$   /$$     ",
};  

  // You must free the result if result is non-NULL.
char *str_replace(char *orig, char *rep, char *with) {
    char *result; // the return string
    char *ins;    // the next insert point
    char *tmp;    // varies
    int len_rep;  // length of rep (the string to remove)
    int len_with; // length of with (the string to replace rep with)
    int len_front; // distance between rep and end of last rep
    int count;    // number of replacements

    if (!orig || !rep)
        return NULL;
    len_rep = strlen(rep);
    if (len_rep == 0)
        return NULL; 
    if (!with)
        with = "";
    len_with = strlen(with);

    ins = orig;
    for (count = 0; tmp = strstr(ins, rep); ++count) {
        ins = tmp + len_rep;
    }

    tmp = result = malloc(strlen(orig) + (len_with - len_rep) * count + 1);

    if (!result)
        return NULL;

    while (count--) {
        ins = strstr(orig, rep);
        len_front = ins - orig;
        tmp = strncpy(tmp, orig, len_front) + len_front;
        tmp = strcpy(tmp, with) + len_with;
        orig += len_front + len_rep; // move to next "end of rep"
    }
    strcpy(tmp, orig);
    return result;
}
  
void main(){
    for(int ii=0; ii < sizeof(LOGO)/40; ii++)
        printf("%s\n", NEW_STRING(LOGO[ii]));
}
```

Comment: Your solution is too complicated: why not print one character at a time, testing for `'$'`? Also the `main` prototype is invalid.

Comment: Solution is more general, so seems complicated. Someone looking for another color or any other string replacement could easily use same solution. If speed an issue, than your solution is better.